# Consider only part of what is written in a cell Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So in cell let's say "b1" I have a Data validation with the following (whatever is written after the date and a space is the Project name):

05/01/2016 I like icecreams
05/01/2016 Project B: whatever
12/01/2016 Project Me!
18/01/2016 Hello world
01/02/2016 I like chocolate
27/02/2016 Real business

I created a macro that checks the "b1" name and if it is equal it does something. My problem is that I recently added the Date to the data validation because I needed to ease the burden of knowing when the Project started.

In my macros I have for example this variable:
 projectname = Sheet1.Range("b1").Value

This variable no longer gets positive results because the Date is also in the Data validation. I need something like only consider the right part after 11 characters of what is written in "b1". 
How can I change the way the variable is set up in Excel-VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date is always going to be the 11 characters of dd/mm/yyyy plus the space then the variable assignment would be:

```
Dim strCellValue As String
Dim strProjectName As String

strCellValue = Sheet1.Range("b1").Value
strProjectName = Right$(strCellValue, Len(strCellValue) - 11)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works ;) Any way you can do that with just 1 variable?

Comment: Sure you could collapse the two lines into one and have `strProjectName = Right$(Sheet1.Range("b1").Value, Len(Sheet1.Range("b1").Value) - 11)`. I split it into two lines to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: Whatever is faster is what I'll pick. Do you know which one is faster?

Comment: I guess the two line version will be a tiny bit quicker as it only evaluates `b1` once.